# Solution Verification: Number of Paths From (a,b) to (c,d) on Cartesian Plane

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

**The Question**

On an $xy$ plane, how many paths can be made from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative integers. Moves must be made one at a time and can only be made to the right or up.

**My Work**

These problems have a solution of (total moves)!/(right moves)!(upward moves)!. So I figured the answer is $\frac{((c-a)+(d-b))!}{(c-a)!(d-b)!}$ did I do it right guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that’s correct. You can also reason as follows. You must make a total of $(c-a)+(d-b)$ moves; $c-a$ of them must be to the right, and those can occur anywhere in the string of moves. There are $$\binom{(c-a)+(d-b)}{c-a}$$ ways to choose which $c-a$ of the $(c-a)+(d-b)$ moves will be to the right, so there are

$$\binom{(c-a)+(d-b)}{c-a}=\frac{\big((c-a)+(d-b)\big)!}{(c-a)!(d-b)!}$$

possible paths.

Comment: +1. Another way you could think about this solution is by writing Pascal's triangle on the lattice, with $(a,b)$ corresponding to $\binom{0}{0}=1$; there is $1$ way to get to $(a,b)$ from $(a,b)$ (the empty path).  The points $$(a+1,b), (a+2,b),\dots,(c,b)$$ all correspond to entries of $1$ in Pascal's triangle, since the only way to get to them from $(a,b)$ is to move in a horizontal line.

Comment: Similarly, all the points $$(a,b+1),\dots,(a,d)$$ have entries of $1$. Then we can get Pascal's triangle using the fact that the number of paths to $(x,y)$ is equal to the sum of the number of paths to $(x-1,y)$ and the number of paths to $(x,y-1)$ (you have to reach the point from directly to the left or directly from below).